# Does sql server standard come packaged with windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

Does sql server standard come packaged with windows server 2008 r2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the SQL Server database engine does not include a Windows license.  The Windows license would need to be purchased separately.  Be careful which edition of Windows you purchase as different editions have different memory limits.

Answer (score 3):

1. No
2. As usual app it has a `setup.exe` executable

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Did it use to? I swear I read that it did somewhere..

Comment: No, never sql server was packaged with windows. THE ONLY EXCEPTION - Sql Server **DataCenter** or **Parallel Data Warehouse** Editions - they MAY be supplied with Windows by Microsoft, since they run on specific versions of Windows, but the Setup still comes without windows

Comment: SQL Server Data Center edition doesn't include the Windows OS.  Only the PDW does, but it comes with the hardware as well so it is all just a big package.

Comment: @Seth see mrdenny correction

Answer (score 0):

No, the database that comes with windows is the windows internal database. This is a flavor of SQL server embedded.  If you need a free database consider SQL server express.

Answer (score 0):

No SQL is not included in the standard editions or higher.  However you are right, it used to be included in the Small Business Server package, it was primarily there to support the installation of SharePoint.

```
The versions of SQL Server that are included in Windows SBS 2008 
Premium are licensed for installation only in your Windows SBS 
2008 network. You cannot install SQL Server on a server that is 
not in the Windows SBS 2008 domain.
```

You can also get SQL as an add-on for SBS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794697(v=WS.10).aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-small-business-server/editions.aspx